# Determine configurations of a ThreadPoolTaskExecutor

Tags: java, spring

A set of tasks (varied in functionality) in my application need to be performed asynchronously, and may be pooled.

Looks like Spring's `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` is what I can use to get such an executor from the framework itself (rather than creating it myself). However, I am not sure how do I decide the best configurations for the executor, i.e. settings such as "max pool size", "queue capacity" and so on. What are the considerations when making this decision and what settings work best?

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend reading the [javadoc of ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) with great attention, because the behavior of such a pool regarding to queuing is important to understand if you want to avoid problems. The JDK has [Executors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html), which provides factory methods which should give you correctly configured pools. Use these methods, or dig into their source code to understand which parameters (sizes, queue type, etc.) are used for these configurations.

Comment: I did go through the relevant javadocs, but those only explain what those configurations mean. They do not tell WHEN and HOW should those be used/tweaked, and that is what I am looking for.

Comment: The settings depend on the kind of tasks you submit (IO-bound, CPU-bound), on the goal you want (minimum latency, maximum CPU usage?), on the number of processors, on the other threads in the application, etc. I advise you to read Java concurrency in practice, which has a whole chapter about these considerations.